# what is mean by function of expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

in the Introduction to Probability book (Jessica Hwang and Joseph K. Blitzstein) section that discussed the "Law of Unconscious Statistician", said $E(g(X))$ does not equal $g(E(X))$ in general if $g(X)$ is not linear. I have some idea about the expectation of a function (random variable), but I don't have any idea about the function of expectation, my question is what is it and can you provide any examples?

Comment: One basic case is $g(x)=x^2.$ Then $E(X^2)\neq (E(X))^2$ in general. For example, a coin toss to determing $\pm 1$ has $E(X)=0,$ but $E(X^2)=1\neq 0^2=(E(X))^2.$ An expectation is just a number, and $g(E(X))$ is just applying the function $g$ to $E(X).$ Nothing magic about it.